# Jetpack Compose: Make two columns take half of the max width doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The design is like below:

[image]

I'm trying to make the blue and cyan column takes 50% of the top magenta part width.

Here is my code:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Keyboard1() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
        val list = (1.. 9).toMutableList()
        list.add(0)
        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Magenta)
                .padding(2.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)) {
            list.forEach {
                ElevatedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(containerColor = Color.Green, contentColor = Color.Red),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = it.toString(), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                }
            }
        }

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(2.dp, 2.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(0.dp)) {
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, Color.Blue)
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, Color.Cyan)
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .background(color)
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(2.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(1.dp)) {
        repeat(columns) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                repeat(rows) {
                    ElevatedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(containerColor = Color.Green, contentColor = Color.Red),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to set `.fillMaxWidth(0.5f)` of the column:

```
@Composable
    fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
            .background(color)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(2.dp),
```

It doesn't work.

Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `weight` modifier to set both columns with the same width. That modifier can only be set from the parent row (inside `Keyboard1`), as this only makes sense for a child of a row (or of a column). If you try to use this modifier inside `BottomLeftLetterKey`, it doesn't know that that element is a child of row, so it cannot use the `weight`. That's another good reason why we should always expose a parameter in the form of `modifier: Modifier = Modifier` for every Composable function, as we need to give a chance to the parent to configure the child's composable, from the parent's perspective.

So the solution could be something like:

```
@Composable
fun Keyboard1() {
        // ...

        Row(
            // ...
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, Color.Blue, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, Color.Cyan, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier
        .background(color)
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(2.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(1.dp)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The main changes from the original code are:

- The function `BottomLeftLetterKey` now receives a modifier parameter;
- The root element of `BottomLeftLetterKey` (i.e. the `Column`) needs to use that modifier parameter instead of using a brand new one. Notice how we changed `Column(modifier = Modifier...)` to `Column(modifier = modifier...)`.
- When we call the function `BottomLeftLetterKey`, we now pass a weight of 1 to both of them. That means that they should have the same width. As there are only two of them, that means 50% for each. The weight value doesn't have to be 1, what matters is that both elements have the exact same weight.